# Add minimap to netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

Is there a way for me to add a minimap plugins to netbeans ide so i can get a small overview of my code files? Ive used vsc before and the minimap helps a lot after a certain threshold

Comment: There's an outdated plugin on GitHub (https://github.com/Chris2011/nb-codeoutline). I haven't tried it myself so I have no clue if it's still compatible with newer version or how much work it would take to make it work.